# Formating Headers of dataframes with openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am currently using the below code to write the first two dataframes into two different sheets in an excel workbook and then a loop to select dataframes from a list and write those to a seperate sheet.I want to format the headers of the dataframes in the list so i used :

```
    book=load_workbook(desktop+'test.xlsx')
    writer =pd.ExcelWriter(desktop+'/test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
    frameg.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet 1',startrow=1,index = False,header= False)         
    framed.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet 2',startrow=1,index=False,header=False )
    for df in ls2:    
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='test',startrow=writer.sheets['test'].max_row+1,header=True,index=False)
        header_format = book.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        'valign': 'top',
        'fg_color': '#5C5C5C',
        'font_color':'#ffffff',
        'border': 1})
        for col_num, value in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
            ws.write(0, col_num , value, header_format)
   writer.save()
```

I am getting an **AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there some code missing? You call `workbook.add_format()` and `worksheet.write()` but those aren't defined here. Did you mean to call `book.add_format()` ?

Comment: @sj95126 Yeaah you re right just edited my code thank you

Comment: The problem might be that you are using `openpyxl` instead of eg. `xlsxwriter`.
As I have a similar issue I would be interested in an 'openpyxl` solution as well.